# Magento 2.2.6 Pagination not working in Category pages

Tags: magento2, category-products, pagination

We have upgraded **Magento 2.2.3 to 2.2.6**.

After upgrade page filter is not working. It is loading all the products in category page.

The drop down still says **9,18,27**.

But it is displaying all products on the page.

Has anyone faced the same issue? Please help me.

Comment: have you any custom extension for layer navigation ?

Comment: @AmitBera, no i using default magento funtionlaity

Comment: I have just upgraded from Magento 2.2.4 to Magento 2.2.7 and I could not find any such issue. I know the versions mentioned in the question and in my comment are different, but it is just to indicate that default Magento does not have such issue. You may have some custom modifications in the core files or there may be some custom module causing the problem.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora, How can i debug this issue please?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora, getting this error in log Bucket does not exist

Comment: @jafar-pinjar Any solution to this? I have also ran into this exact issue using Magento 2.2.4

Comment: @ne0nlight, Yes I had installed one third party layered navigation extension. That was causing the issue.